# How to prove theorem about list of pairs

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I tried to continue proving [this practice example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947645/handling-let-in-hypothesis) that is about list of pairs, but it seems impossible. How should I continue to solve this theorem?

```
Require Import List.

Fixpoint split (A B:Set)(x:list (A*B)) : (list A)*(list B) :=
 match x with
   |nil => (nil, nil)
   |cons (a,b) x1 => let (ta, tb) := split A B x1 in (a::ta, b::tb)
 end.

Theorem split_eq_len : 
forall (A B:Set)(x:list (A*B))(y:list A)(z:list B),(split A B x)=(y,z) -> 
length y = length z.
Proof.
intros A B x.
elim x.
simpl.
intros y z.
intros H.
injection H.
intros H1 H2.
rewrite <- H1.
rewrite <- H2.
reflexivity.
intros hx.
elim hx.
intros a b tx H y z.
simpl.
intro.
destruct (split A B tx).
```

Comment: @Anton: Please pay attention to the question, I'm asking how to continue this prove. the last suggestion, in the URL you mentioned, was to use "destruct (split A B tx)" but no other idea on how to finish the proof completely.

Comment: I retracted my close vote, since you edited your post, clarifying your exact question. It's always a good idea to mention your original sources to show your appreciation to the author of the original proof attempt and to prevent possible confusion. Thanks and enjoy theorem proving!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me show you a couple of steps you can take to advance your proof.
You have ended up in this proof state:

```
H0 : (a :: l, b :: l0) = (y, z)
============================
length y = length z
```

At this point it should be obvious that `y` and `z` are some non-empty lists. So `injection H0.` (or `inversion H0.` as suggested by Tej Chajed) helps you with this.

Then you can change your goal into

```
length l = length l0
```

using a combination of simplifications and rewrites (it depends on the exact tactic you use, `inversion` makes it simpler). You may also find the `f_equal` tactic very useful. At this point you are almost done because you can now use your induction hypothesis.

Comment: That's very helpful. You are professional. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to just give you a proof, but here's one hint:

Your proof will be a bit simpler if you use `inversion H` instead of `injection H` and `subst` instead of rewriting with equalities (`subst` takes any equality `v = expr` where `v` is a variable and substitutes `expr` for `v` everywhere; it then clears out the variable `v`).

Comment: Thank you Tej, but your hint is just about the first case of the prove that is the nil case and its prove is straightforward. I need hints for the second case, the inductive step.

Comment: @Amir - There is no inductive step in your code because you aren't doing induction anywhere, which is what this answer suggests you do.

Comment: @Lee `elim` introduces the induction hypothesis. So, it's totally provable in this formulation.

Comment: You're right @AntonTrunov, I didn't realize exactly what `elim` does. I'll remove that part of my answer.